# Why is my WHERE clause not filtering the year in my date column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to filter dates, but for example, when I enter the code below, I get all dates after July 1, regardless of the year.  In includes 2015, and 2016 items.  What I am doing wrong?  The original TicketDate column is Text format in our database, that's why I converted.

```
SELECT
  EmplCode,
  Comments,
  EmplName,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(TicketDate AS DATE), 1) AS TicketDate,
  CreatedBy,
  ActClockInTime,
  ActClockOutTime,
  AdjClockInTime,
  AdjClockOutTime,
  ROUND(TotActTime, 2) AS ActualTime,
  ROUND(TotAdjTime, 2) AS AdjActualTime,
  PayrollRate,
  OverTime,
  Holiday,
  GLAcct
FROM AttendDet
WHERE 
  EmplCode IS NOT NULL
  AND TicketDate > '07/01/17'
ORDER BY TicketDate;
```

Comment: What data type is `TicketDate`? Try using an ISO date constant: `'2017-07-01'`. PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `TicketDate` is not a `date` data type, then you need to convert it to one.

Also: The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

```
select
  EmplCode,
  Comments,
  EmplName,
  convert(varchar(30), cast(TicketDate as date), 1) as TicketDate,
  CreatedBy,
  ActClockInTime,
  ActClockOutTime,
  AdjClockInTime,
  AdjClockOutTime,
  round(TotActTime, 2) as ActualTime,
  round(TotAdjTime, 2) as AdjActualTime,
  PayrollRate,
  OverTime,
  Holiday,
  glacct
from AttendDet
where EmplCode is not null
  and convert(date,TicketDate) > '20170701'
order by TicketDate;
```

Also, always include a size for `varchar` and `nvarchar`.

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.